# Remove WS-Addressing/WS-Security sections from WSE 3.0 Client request

Tags: c#, web-services, wse3.0

I've got a simple C# web service proxy class that I created with WSDL.exe.  I am invoking a method on the remote web service, and it is including a bunch of WS-Addressing and WS-Security headers that I do not want (and that the server is choking on).  Here is an example of the raw soap request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
  xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" 
  xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" 
  xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
  <soap:Header>
    <wsa:Action></wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:22f12267-b162-4703-a451-2d1c5c5a619b</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:To>http://example.com/wstest</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security>
      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-5c9f0ef0-ab45-421d-a633-4c4fad26d945">
        <wsu:Created>2009-04-15T16:27:25Z</wsu:Created>
        <wsu:Expires>2009-04-15T16:32:25Z</wsu:Expires>
      </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Func1 xmlns="http://example.com">
      <arg_1 xmlns="">blah</arg_1>
      <arg_2 xmlns="">blah2</arg_2></arg_2>
    </Func1>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

But **I don't care about the WS-Addressing/WS-Security stuff**.  I've done nothing to include it.  The .NET WSE 3.0 package seems to be adding them by default.  Is there any way to get rid of these?  I can see no properties on my proxy object that allow me to remove these sections.  I've tried:

```
proxyObject.Addressing.Clear();
proxyObject.Security.Clear();
```

Those cause a null reference exception when I invoke my web service method.

I want the SOAP request to look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope 
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Header>
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <Func1 xmlns="http://example.com">
      <arg_1 xmlns="">blah</arg_1>
      <arg_2 xmlns="">blah2</arg_2></arg_2>
    </Func1>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you are using WCF then this SO question may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24635950/remove-timestamp-element-from-ws-security-headers-created-by-wcf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I ended up using a technique I have used in the past.  I created classes that implement **SoapFilter** and **PolicyAssertion** which allow me to modify the raw XML of the SOAP request before it is sent.  Below is an example:

```
    public class MyPolicy : SoapFilter
    {
        public override SoapFilterResult ProcessMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
        {
            // Remove all WS-Addressing and WS-Security header info
            envelope.Header.RemoveAll();

            return SoapFilterResult.Continue;
        }
    }

    public class MyAssertion : PolicyAssertion
    {
        public override SoapFilter CreateClientInputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override SoapFilter CreateClientOutputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
        {
            return new MyPolicy();
        }

        public override SoapFilter CreateServiceInputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
        {
            return null;
        }

        public override SoapFilter CreateServiceOutputFilter(FilterCreationContext context)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Then in your web service proxy's contructor you apply the policy:

```
/// <remarks/>
    [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Web.Services", "2.0.50727.1433")]
    [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
    [System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]       
 [System.Web.Services.WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name="MyBinding", Namespace="http://example.com")]
    public partial class MyWebClient : WebServicesClientProtocol {

        // ... member variables here

        /// <remarks/>
        public MyWebClient()
        {
            this.Url = "http://example.com";           
            if ((this.IsLocalFileSystemWebService(this.Url) == true)) {
                this.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = false;
            }
            else {
                this.useDefaultCredentialsSetExplicitly = true;
            }

            // Apply policy here
            Policy policy = new Policy();
            policy.Assertions.Add(new MyAssertion());
            this.SetPolicy(policy); 
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

to remove the addressing header i used the below code in one of my app.

```
  public override void SecureMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope, Security security)
    {
       //remove addressing Header from envelope

        AddressingHeaders objAH = new AddressingHeaders(envelope);

        objAH.RemoveXml(envelope);


        //Add Wahtever security token you want to add.

        security.Tokens.Add(bla-bla-bla);

    }
```

I used **SecureMessage** function because i wanted to add security tokens,but same code can be used in **ProcessMessage** function.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if your problem might not also have ben resolved by simply not using WSE?

Comment: Believe me if I could I would.  The issue is that I need MTOM support and for .NET 2.0 this only comes with WSE (as far as I can tell)

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer in this page, I added the code below to remove specific header (by tagname) recursively from XML.

```
Public Overrides Function ProcessMessage(ByVal envelope As SoapEnvelope) As SoapFilterResult
    ' Remove all WS-Addressing and WS-Security header info
    RemoveTag(envelope.DocumentElement, "wsa:Action")
    RemoveTag(envelope.DocumentElement, "wsa:MessageID")
    RemoveTag(envelope.DocumentElement, "wsa:To")
    Return SoapFilterResult.[Continue]
End Function

Private Sub RemoveTag(ByVal XE As System.Xml.XmlElement, ByVal TagName As String)
    For Each N As XmlNode In XE
        If N.ChildNodes.Count > 0 Then
            RemoveTag(N, TagName)
        End If
        If N.Name = TagName Then
            XE.RemoveChild(N)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the easiest way to remove these addressing and security headers was to change the web service configuration to use `BasicHttpBinding` instead of `WSHttp binding`.