# Removing certain Elements from Header - that were created by WSE 3.0

Tags: .net, xml, soap, wse3.0

I am working with a wsdl which is automatically adding extra elements into the xml. In order for it to comply with an external web service that do not use these elements.  See the following image:
http://img406.imageshack.us/img406/1307/differencese.png
Left = Red elements need removed - Right = What i need it to output

i have attached the code that is creating my envelope and payload.

```
    Dim content As myProxy.Content = New myProxy.Content
    Dim inputguid As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    Dim service As myProxy.WebService = New myProxy.WebService
    Dim str As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim payload As myProxy.Payload = New myProxy.Payload

    'payload
    str.LoadXml(xmlstr)

    'manifest
    service.payloadManifest = New myProxy.PayloadManifest
    service.payloadManifest.manifest = New myProxy.Manifest() {New myProxy.Manifest}
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).element = "GetVehicleServiceHistory"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).namespaceURI = ""
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).contentID = "Content0"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).version = "2.01"
    service.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11

    service.UserAgent = "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"
    Dim usertoken As New Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.UsernameToken("userid", "password", Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.Tokens.PasswordOption.SendPlainText)

    service.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(usertoken)
    service.RequestSoapContext.Security.MustUnderstand = False

    payload.content = New myProxy.Content() {content}
    ReDim Preserve payload.content(0)
    payload.content(0).Any = str.DocumentElement
    payload.content(0).id = "Content0"

    service.Url = "http://localhost:8080"
    service.ProcessMessage(payload)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Michael

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753327/remove-ws-addressing-ws-security-sections-from-wse-3-0-client-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    Dim content As blah.Content = New blah.Content
    Dim inputguid As String = Guid.NewGuid.ToString
    Dim service As blah.WebService = New blah.WebService
    Dim str As New System.Xml.XmlDocument
    Dim payload As blah.Payload = New blah.Payload

    'payload
    str.LoadXml(xmlstr)

    'manifest
    service.payloadManifest = New blah.PayloadManifest
    service.payloadManifest.manifest = New blah.Manifest() {New blah.Manifest}
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).element = "GetVehicleServiceHistory"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).namespaceURI = ""
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).contentID = "Content0"
    service.payloadManifest.manifest(0).version = "2.01"
    service.SoapVersion = SoapProtocolVersion.Soap11

    service.UserAgent = "Jakarta Commons-HttpClient/3.1"


    payload.content = New blah.Content() {content}
    ReDim Preserve payload.content(0)
    payload.content(0).Any = str.DocumentElement
    payload.content(0).id = "Content0"

    service.ProcessMessage(payload)
```

noticed i've removed the WSE coding:-

within the web reference reference.vb i've added the following code in the pcublic sub new -

```
        Dim policy As New Policy()
        policy.Assertions.Add(New MyAssertion())
        Me.SetPolicy(policy)
```

and then

```
Public Class MyPolicy
    Inherits SoapFilter
    Public Overrides Function ProcessMessage(ByVal envelope As SoapEnvelope) As SoapFilterResult
        'creating the <wsse:Security> element in the outgoing message
        Dim securityNode As XmlNode = envelope.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "wsse:Security", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
        Dim securityAttr As XmlAttribute = envelope.CreateAttribute("soap:mustunderstand")
        securityAttr.Value = "1"
        'creating the <wsse:usernameToken> element
        Dim usernameTokenNode As XmlNode = envelope.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "wsse:UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
        Dim userElement As XmlElement = usernameTokenNode
        userElement.SetAttribute("xmlns:wsu", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd")


        'creating the <wsse:Username> element
        Dim userNameNode As XmlNode = envelope.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "wsse:Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
        userNameNode.InnerXml = "username"


        'creating the <wsse:password> element
        Dim pwdNode As XmlNode = envelope.CreateNode(XmlNodeType.Element, "wsse:Password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd")
        Dim pwdElement As XmlElement = pwdNode
        pwdElement.SetAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText")
        pwdNode.InnerXml = "password"

        usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(userNameNode)
        usernameTokenNode.AppendChild(pwdNode)
        securityNode.AppendChild(usernameTokenNode)
        envelope.ImportNode(securityNode, True)
        Dim node As XmlNode = envelope.Header
        node.AppendChild(securityNode)


        Dim actionnode As XmlNode = envelope.Header("wsa:Action")
        envelope.Header.RemoveChild(actionnode)

        Dim messageNode As XmlNode = envelope.Header("wsa:MessageID")
        envelope.Header.RemoveChild(messageNode)

        Dim replyToNode As XmlNode = envelope.Header("wsa:ReplyTo")
        envelope.Header.RemoveChild(replyToNode)

        Dim toNode As XmlNode = envelope.Header("wsa:To")
        envelope.Header.RemoveChild(toNode)

        Return SoapFilterResult.[Continue]
    End Function
End Class

Public Class MyAssertion
    Inherits PolicyAssertion
    Public Overrides Function CreateClientInputFilter(ByVal context As FilterCreationContext) As SoapFilter
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CreateClientOutputFilter(ByVal context As FilterCreationContext) As SoapFilter
        Return New MyPolicy()
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CreateServiceInputFilter(ByVal context As FilterCreationContext) As SoapFilter
        Return Nothing
    End Function

    Public Overrides Function CreateServiceOutputFilter(ByVal context As FilterCreationContext) As SoapFilter
        Return Nothing
    End Function
End Class
```

Public Overrides Function ProcessMessage - overwrites the processmessage and lets me manually edit the envelope

i needed to manually remove the elements i did not need and manually insert the elements Idid need:

Answer (score 0):

You could write a [SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx). I've done this in the past to clean away illegal characters from a SOAP response, but you can use it to modify your request as well. Basically it will intercept the SOAP package before it's being sent, or when you receive it, but before .Net deserializes it.

Stefan Goßner has an old blog post which explains [how build a SoapExtension](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2009/08/26/how-to-deal-with-invalid-characters-in-soap-responses-from-asp-net-web-services.aspx). You would put your code inside the `ProcessOutput` method.

The drawback is that you are parsing the SOAP message as text, but can of course load it up in an `XDocument` or `XmlDocument` if that works better. But you are also passing it on as text afterwards.

If you are using WCF, then check out [Intercept messages in a WCF Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1217374/intercept-messages-in-a-wcf-client), as you have to implement a `IClientMessageInspector` for the SOAP interception.

Hope this helps you a bit on the way.