# WCF or WSE Edit security header

Tags: wcf, wse

I've been trying to change the soap security element either using WCF or WSE.

1. WCF: Implement a messageinspector and add your custom code in Beforerequestsent. Having set the following  custom binding in the code behind, I don't see a security element in ref System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message request` There is a envelope and Header, Body but missing security element in header.

   ```
   AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement secBE = AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateDuplexBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity11WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);
   X509SecurityTokenParameters x509ProtectionParameters = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
   x509ProtectionParameters.RequireDerivedKeys = false;
   x509ProtectionParameters.X509ReferenceStyle = X509KeyIdentifierClauseType.SubjectKeyIdentifier;
   x509ProtectionParameters.ReferenceStyle = SecurityTokenReferenceStyle.Internal;
   x509ProtectionParameters.InclusionMode = SecurityTokenInclusionMode.AlwaysToRecipient;
   ```

   This is what the ref variable request looks like

   ```
   <s:Envelope xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">  <s:Header>    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1" />    <a:MessageID>urn:uuid:4e929e4c-882b-40dc-9794-e54b71c47148</a:MessageID>    <a:ReplyTo>      <a:Address>http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/anonymous</a:Address>    
   </a:ReplyTo>    
       <VsDebuggerCausalityData xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/vstudio/diagnostics/servicemodelsink">uIDPo9rzFi9T6thDniQ9lRMdE0sAAAAA1RxuI+tGxUi69I44BS9+QcTNP3q82D9HmHmB8kuqWioACQAA</VsDebuggerCausalityData> 
    </s:Header> 
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">    <getEligibility xmlns="http://org/emedny/mhs/">      <input>        <transData</transData>      </input>  
     </getEligibility> 
     </s:Body>
   </s:Envelope>
   ```

   Although fiddler shows an outgoing security header, I am unable to get to the Security element in the Before request sent method
2. WSE: They recommend using a soap filter and override a few methods
   I have all the tokens in code behind

   ```
       ProxyGenerationWSDL.MHService MHs = new MHService();
       X509Certificate2 cert = GetCertificateFromStore("User");
       X509SecurityToken x5091 = new X509SecurityToken(cert);
       MHs.SetClientCredential(x5091);
       X509Certificate2 cert2 = GetCertificateFromStore("Server");
       X509SecurityToken x5092 = new X509SecurityToken(cert2);
       MHs.SetServiceCredential(x5092);
       UsernameToken tkuser = new UsernameToken("User1", "Pwd", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);
       MHs.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(x5091);
       MHs.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(x5092);
       MHs.RequestSoapContext.Security.Tokens.Add(tkuser);
       Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.EncryptedData data = new Microsoft.Web.Services3.Security.EncryptedData(x5092);
       MHs.RequestSoapContext.Security.Elements.Add(new MessageSignature(x5091));
   ```

   Now created a custom policy, policy assertion where I am overriding the following

   ```
   public class ClientOutputFilter : SoapFilter
   {
       public ClientOutputFilter()
           : base()
       { }

       public override SoapFilterResult ProcessMessage(SoapEnvelope envelope)
       {    
               XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
               string s = envelope.InnerXml;
               document.LoadXml(envelope.InnerXml);  //loading soap message as string 
               string path = "/*:Envelope/*:Header/*:Security/*:TimeStamp";
               XmlNodeList ndlist =
               document.SelectNodes(path);
   //then remove the timestamp element from the security header
   ```

   But even here the envelope has no security element.

Please suggest. What methods are to be overridden in order to edit the security header

Edited: Request which appears now

```
        <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-993b00fe-4c5c-43e8-9882-c59c1e5d1179-7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">--Removed--
        </o:BinarySecurityToken>
     <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-993b00fe-4c5c-43e8-9882-c59c1e5d1179-7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">--Removed--
        </o:BinarySecurityToken>
    <o:Username>UserName</o:Username>
<o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PWD</o:Password>
</o:UsernameToken>
```

What needs to appear

```
<o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-993b00fe-4c5c-43e8-9882-c59c1e5d1179-7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">--Removed--
  </o:BinarySecurityToken>
  <o:BinarySecurityToken u:Id="uuid-993b00fe-4c5c-43e8-9882-c59c1e5d1179-7" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" 
        EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">--Removed--
  </o:BinarySecurityToken>
  <o:Username>UserName</o:Username>
    <o:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PWD</o:Password>
    <o:Nonce>XXXX</o:Nonce>
    <o:Created>TTT</o:Created>
 </o:UsernameToken>
```

Edited to show
Complete Soap request to show signing and  encryption details

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mhs="http://org/emedny/mhs/" xmlns:urn="urn:hl7-org:v3">
<soapenv:Header>
<wsse:Security soap:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d">MIICeDCC....(eMedNY signed user MLS cert).......</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    <wsse:BinarySecurityToken ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3" EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685">MIIDFj.....( eMedNY MLS web-service end-point public cert)........</wsse:BinarySecurityToken>
    <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-970e9a80-00cc-4c86-8ec4-3ba16e029a5b">
    <wsse:Username>....your_username.....</wsse:Username>
    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">.....your_plaintext_password....</wsse:Password>
    <wsse:Nonce>KNyu6MsXCkTg4DDyvwvEiw==</wsse:Nonce>
    <wsu:Created>2010-09-15T18:00:30Z</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
    <xenc:EncryptedKey xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5"/>
    <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-c0cc2cd4-cb77-4fa5-abfa-bd485afd1685" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
    <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>gpBAWt91pdwhKva............</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:ReferenceList>
    <xenc:DataReference URI="#Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794"/>
    </xenc:ReferenceList>
    </xenc:EncryptedKey>
    <Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <SignedInfo>
    SAMP L E R EQUE ST W I T H WS S E CURI T Y
    eMedNY Meds History Service User Guide Page 13 of 48 February 16, 2012
    Version 1.1
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"/>
    <SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/>
    <Reference URI="#Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b">
    <Transforms>
    <Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/>
    </Transforms>
    <DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/>
    <DigestValue>wRUq.........</DigestValue>
    </Reference>
    </SignedInfo>
    <SignatureValue>tBSsaZi........</SignatureValue>
    <KeyInfo>
    <wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    <wsse:Reference URI="#SecurityToken-e00c8062-83d2-4f04-88fc-996218e7bb3d" ValueType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-x509-token-profile-1.0#X509v3"/>
    </wsse:SecurityTokenReference>
    </KeyInfo>
    </Signature>
    </wsse:Security>
    </soapenv:Header>
    <soapenv:Body wsu:Id="Id-f10674fd-b999-47c9-9568-c11fa5e5405b" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
    <xenc:EncryptedData Id="Enc-0641b860-b16d-4941-91c0-d60bece67794" Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Content" xmlns:xenc="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
    <xenc:EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#tripledes-cbc"/>
    <xenc:CipherData>
    <xenc:CipherValue>SQsTCAK6ZaVhojB8+Y.........</xenc:CipherValue>
    </xenc:CipherData>
    </xenc:EncryptedData>
    </soapenv:Body>
```

Comment: Do you have any idea about IClientMessageInspector, IDispatchMessageInspector and IEndpointBehavior
i have mainupulated the soap message before sending with these.Check it might help you

Comment: @ Kamran Shahid: what abt WSE. How do I remove the timetamp node from security

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In WCF you need to use a [custom message encoder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx). The inspector is called too early to change security. If you will share more details on the exact change you want to make maybe we can help with a better way.

Comment: For WCF this is what I was lookin at may not be the best way to handle it.. I was considering adding a usernametoken with nonce in beforerequestsent. I would be adding two X509's using mutualcertificate in code behind custombinding and then do some Transformmessage, hardcoding to the security element.  and insert a usernametoken+nonce. For WSE, nonce is not a problem, but it adds an additonal security timestamp. So i was looking to remove this in Soap filter

Comment: I really don't want to do Customcredentials and implement all custom tokens.. It seems tooo complicated..

Comment: maybe this token can be usefull. it replaces the regular wcf username and adds nonce capabilities. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aszego/archive/2010/06/24/usernametoken-profile-vs-wcf.aspx

Comment: also please publish the message you get now and how it should look like after the change

Comment: Please see edits.. I have added how the request looks now and how it is supposed to look like.

Comment: in wcf your only options are a custom encoder or the custom token in the link from my previous comment. note the first option is a custom encoder not custom token. so you just need to implement one method and copy&paste the rest of the code). In the second link they implemented all the tokens for you.

Comment: Ok got it.. What is the method to implement in Custom encoder..  Also, one another thing, In my soap request only the body is encrypted, signed. Which of these above methods suggested would be flexible to add that additional coding?. I believe WCF encrypts and signs all by default. If you want to see the encrypted part, see edit

Comment: WSE does this with very few lines of coding. But it generates a timestamp element in the security header.(this is for WSE).<wsse:Security s:mustUnderstand="1"><wsse:Timestamp u:Id="uuid-f431423c-60df-4a01-ba63-d768c2833d86-2"><wsse:Created>2013-06-22T20:18:18.794Z</wsse:Created><wsse:Expires>2013-06-22T20:23:18.794Z</u:Expires></wsse:Timestamp> The server rejects this element.

Comment: can you remove the timestamp in wse or is it signed?

Comment: this is a sample for a message encoder http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751486.aspx

Comment: you should not add code within the encoder to take care of signature/encryption. you need to configure the wcf binding directly

Comment: Just out of interest,In WSE if I need to delete a timestamp element from security header, where would I start.. Start by making my own policy, policy assertions. What goes is these assertiosn.. can't use the builtin usernameassertion token and muutalassertion11. Because by default these are added.. .. Any suggestions?.. So all I am left with is a custom encoder in WCF. I will give it a try

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/753327/remove-ws-addressing-ws-security-sections-from-wse-3-0-client-request

Comment: Yes I looked at that... But he does a envelope.Header.RemoveAll() in the ProcessMessage.. I just need to remove the timestamp