# How to remove <wsse:security> from the soap header?

Tags: asmx, wse3.0

How can I remove the  from the soap header?

I am using WSE 3.0 and I want to remove this

```
<wsse:Security>
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-3abc1d4b-faa4-423c-9987-54e0f49a5782">
            <wsu:Created>2014-04-07T06:15:35Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2014-04-07T06:20:35Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
    </wsse:Security>
```

How can I remove this. [Removing Security header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/753327/remove-ws-addressing-ws-security-sections-from-wse-3-0-client-request)

I am using .net c# 4.0 Asmx approach to create a proxy class of java web service

Comment: First of all, were you aware that WSE is obsolete? Second, why do you want to remove the header? And do you want to remove it when you send it or when you receive it?

Comment: And what is a ".net c# 4.0 Asmx java web service"?

Comment: I know it is obsolete, I want to remove it in request. I am using asmx approach to create a proxy class of a java web service. Sorry I will correct that

Comment: Sorry, you didn't answer my question. Why do you want to remove the header? And why are you using WSE?

Comment: WSE was used in our project from years back, and we are still in the process of implementing the WCF approach, till then we want the other code to work as it is. WSE header contains the credentials that are passed and it is not set anywhere to pass that header. Still it is able to send in the request.

Comment: It is still very unclear to me why you want to remove the header.

Comment: Security header in the project is sending the Username in the request under the security header which i have not posted in the code. I want to remove that in the header. I dont want WSSE security header completely.

Comment: But, if the service requires the header, then you're going to have a problem.

Comment: ah,okay, but cant we trim this if we having a log which is a text file for our application. That is when we trying to write this to a log.?

Comment: Did you know that this is the first time you have spoken about logging?

Comment: John Saunders: we don't all have the freedom to do things in any fashion we please. If you don't have a useful answer, try not railing on the OP. Maybe just move along. If you suspect you can help the user by suggesting something other than an answer, you could certainly find more polite ways to offer.